# About Button in Layout

Tags: android, button

[image]I placed a `Button` in a layout

here is my xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" 
    android:textColor="#ff0000"/>
```

and wrote the following code in activity:

```
public class Basic extends Activity {

    Button btn;

    public void oncreate(Bundle b) {
        super.onCreate(b);
        setContentView(R.layout.first);
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    }

    public void clkBtn(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "hai.........", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

When I run this code, I am getting white blank screen (without any button). Can any one tell me what is wrong with my code?

Comment: show me first.xml layout file.

Comment: and your xml please...

Comment: Post your `AndroidManifest.xml`. I suspect the app is opening main activity which is blank.

Answer (score 0):

Update your **first.xml** under `res->layout` folder like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="clkBtn"
        android:text="Click Me" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the `Button` event you need to first register your `Button` for that. The code which you have written is right but to invoke that method you have to add the property `android:onClick="clkBtn"` in your layout file.

**OR**

If you don't want to use this way then you can also explicitly invoke the event by registering your `Button` in your class as below:

```
public class Basic extends Activity {

    Button btn;
    public void oncreate(Bundle b) {
        super.onCreate(b);
        setContentView(R.layout.first);
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btn.setOnClickListener(this); 
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "hai.........", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
    }
```

And also to launch your activity make sure have added your activity as launcher in your manifest file as below .

```
 <activity android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:name="Basic" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
  </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is My Answer. In XML file Button should be like this:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/ID of you button "
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Name To Display Button name" />
```

In the MainActivity OR In any activity (in which you have called XML):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

public void oncreate(Bundle paramBundle) {
    super.onCreate(paramBundle);

    setContentView(R.layout."Your XML file in which Button is.");

  Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id."Your button Id");

  btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
        //Do your onclick program here  

        }
    });
}
}
```